# Can we set newsfeed and secondary owner for my site clean up using PowerShell script ?

Tags: powershell, user-profile, my-site, mysites

Can we set newsfeed and secondary owner for my site clean up using PowerShell script?  Please refere path "Central Admin-->Application Management-->Manage Service Applications-->User Profile Service Application-->SetUp My Sites" and screenshot for more information.I need to set these tabs using PowerShell for automation purpose.

[image]